# phpexcel save column in mysqldatabase as defined

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpexcel

I need to manage data in different columns of MySQL database from excel files. Right now I am trying to import excel files but complete data is getting saved in a single column of mysql instead of different columns according to excel file structure. I am attaching basic structure of database that I am developing and I am looking forward for some reliable support because it has already taken a lot time and I have passed the deadline as well :(

iterator.php is the file that I am currently using to handle the issue but no success so far :( Looking forward for your help.

```
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("example.xlsm");

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    echo 'Worksheet - ' , $worksheet->getTitle() , EOL;

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        echo '    Row number - ' , $row->getRowIndex() , EOL;

        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            if (!is_null($cell)) {
                echo '        Cell - ' , $cell->getCoordinate() , ' - ' , $cell->getCalculatedValue() , EOL;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my database table structure [1]: image http://i40.tinypic.com/2wlyedd.png "Data Base Table Structure Image"
regards Ahsan,

Comment: Show your database table structure

Comment: @MarkBaker i edit my question in more details with database structure image please read it again

Comment: I cringe when I see this: because you have a database structure that doesn't really hold enough information (as shown by your previous question), and that will be problematic to work with, that stores all data as strings irrespective of datatype (date, integer, float, rich text, string, Boolean). If you need to store that data from an Excel workbook cell-by-cell, why not simply store the entire workbook file?

Comment: But what's the actual problem? Are you having a problem with building a SQL insert?

Comment: @MarkBaker my mission is upload excel file in data base and view in browser same as excel show but problem is it did not able to show like excel style. thats y i am getting problem if you give me database structure and update this file as i need its realy good bcoz its realy hard work for me. thats y. yes 1st problem is insert data in mysql bcoz if insert data perfect then i get data easily. but i dont know how i get data correct form and style easily every row. thats y i need help for done this work.

Comment: and simple is i want upload excel file in database and get output like excel style(or i easily set styling). and give me idea or file or code which is easy and better for me : -)))

Comment: If you really absolutely have to save this information in a database, then you need to add a lot of extra columns in your database table to hold style information (datatype, number format, font, colour, border style and colour, etc.) Even then, you will still run into problems with any rich text in a cell, formulae, etc.

Comment: What you're trying to do is a really bad idea! I don't know how I can emphasise that any more; and there is no justifiable business case that I can see for doing it.

Comment: @MarkBaker ok but it depend on what we get for insert in database from iterator.php file currently i get 4 information's 1 worksheet second row third cell and fourth cell value. that's y i create just 4 column for save these data.

Comment: i just use excel file for upload values. and no more calculation etc. just upload values and view in browser and styling with css is possible ?

Comment: You need to retrieve style information using `$worksheet->getStyle('A1');` for a cell address... all of this is documented

Comment: But save the uploaded file: then you can load it and use the HTML Writer to render it as HTML that can be displayed as a web page - there is no __need__ to store all that information in a database if you subsequently want to display it as HTML

Comment: @MarkBaker but if i don't save all information in database then how can i add more value in already exist data ? project is upload file information's in database and if upload another file then add in already exist data in database

Comment: To add more data.... load the uploaded workbook, add the extra data, save

Comment: USING A DATABASE FOR THIS IS AN INCREDIBLY BAD IDEA. DON'T DO IT

Comment: look @MarkBaker i think i need to tell you complete info 1st upload file and if file data exist in database then (+)add data into already exist data in database.
i am using database bcoz i think its better but i think i am wrong. what you say about it? there is another way to do this ?

Comment: @MarkBaker load and save uploaded file .. ? u mean save via ms excel ?

Comment: hmmm ok i understand and thank full to you how you treate me maybe no 1 here who listen and understand my question (Y) i know after this comment my id is block ahha but Thank You Greate You Are also sorry for my bad english i am not understand any language only Urdu and english just little bit :-D:pppPPp SEE AGAIN BYE Allah Bless You :-$